# LDAP Custom Filters - Error

Tags: active-directory, ldap, websphere-liberty

I'm getting this error when running an application on a WebSphere Liberty Profile Application Server

> CWIML4520E: The LDAP operation could not be completed. The LDAP naming exception javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: Unbalanced parenthesis; remaining name 'o=LogonLDAP'; resolved object com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@1eb445ee occurred during processing.

**LDAP User Registry Info:**

```
Base distinguished name: o=LogonLDAP  

Bind distinguished name: cn=wsDeveloper,ou=Members,o=LogonLDAP
```

**Custom Filter Info:**

```
User Filter: (&amp;(cn=%v)(objectClass=User))    
User ID Map: *:cn

Group Filter: (&amp;(cn=%v)(objectClass=group))  
Group ID Map: *:cn
```

I don't have any unbalanced parenthesis in my filters and I've tried a bunch of different combinations. Can anyone help out here?

Comment: The error is coming from the Base distinguished name because when I change that to "O=LogonLDAP" the error changes to "Unbalanced parenthesis; remaining name 'O=LogonLDAP';"

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by removing the 'amp;' from my user and group filter. I was editing this through the designer page not directly in the XML source file. When I put '&' in the designer page field it was causing the XML source file to contain '&amp;' which was causing an error.